# Looking for identical sequences over all users

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to get the identical pathes (with counts) of all users

Hey everybody, 
Want to keep the question short and hopefully it‘s clear what I want. 
I have a table in BigQuery. There I have the following columns

```
- UserID
- Timestamp
- Domain
- some other columns (but I guess they are unimportant)
```

I have totally no idea how to fix this!

So I want to look for the same paths over all users and count how many users have the same sequence of domains.

**Problem:** We are talking about 129 000 users and around 5TB of data. I guess I have to limit the amount of path length or something else.

I‘m familiar with SQL but I need some help/input to keep the costs low. Every query costs money and my thought was to ask the community before I spend thousands of Dollars.
Thanks for any input!

***EDIT:*** 
I tried the following to rank the visits of domains:

```
SELECT
    guid,
    domain AS channel,
    timestamp,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY guid ORDER BY timestamp ASC ) AS rank
  FROM
data.all
```

My problem is now: How can I match identical pathes afters merge each "step" in this customer journey?

Comment: . . I don't know what you mean by "sequence of domains".  Sample data and desired results would help.  Pay particular attention to duplicates and identical timestamps.

Comment: With sequences I mean something like domain1@domain2@domain3 .... so just how online user browse in the internet...

Answer (score 0):

This may help or at least help you get started:

```
select domains, count(*)
from (select userid, string_agg(domain order by timestamp, ',') as domains
      from t
      group by userid
     ) u
group by domains;
```

I would prefer to use arrays to store the path itself, but BigQuery does not (yet) support arrays as `GROUP BY` keys.

Comment: Thanks Gordon... will try this and keep you updated

Comment: Hey @PeterKupfer!

If the answer helped you with your issue, would you mind accepting it so that other users can benefit from it =)?